# How do I turn an observable set of two different types to a different third type observable in Typescript with rxjs?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, angular9

So I have a problem of basically I am getting two different services of types Observable and Observable let's say.  They are returned by services and fine on initial load doing something like this (in a constructor of a component in Angular)

```
combineLatest([this.service.A(), this.service.B()])
  ).subscribe(([A, B]) => {
    this.C = A.map(x => {
        return { 
           id: x.id,
           name: x.specificA
        };  //Different type of C 
    }).concat(B.map(x => {
         return {
            id: x.id,
            name: x.specificB
       };
   });
```

So this works when it is done on constructor and the view loads with my 'C' in this example and the world is right.  However I would like to call an update on the rows at times and go full circle back to my collection and then update.  I was thinking of doing a combineLatest but without a subscribe to get an observable on the component of something like C$: Observable.  Then make that object do all the work in subscriptions and further updates.  Then doing the

```
  this.C$ = ([this.service.A(), this.service.B()]).pipe(map( //this is wrong))
```

Basically I don't want to subscribe to the observable but set it up from other observables, THEN subscribe to that.  Potentially do a combo with rxjs to take two observable types and make a third type.  Then when the event of an update happens kick off the subscribe of the 'C$' observable.  I know it is probably a simple operation I am just not getting that someone that is good at rxjs could tell me how to combine.

Comment: are you talking about a higher order function that produce an observable stream that does the data subscription and manipulation?

Comment: @FanCheung Correct.  I want to manipulate an observable of C that I can subscribe to and when I add or remove to collection A or B it calls observable C that I have made that goes through both from full round server call again.

Answer (score 1):

Your first `combineLatest` seems almost as the solution.

Since the mapping operation for both types is different, first I would create an observable fore each type that maps them to the third type, and then merge them to single observable of the third type.

Let's go over it, assume I have these 3 types:

```js
interface ModelA { aSpecific: string; }
interface ModelB { bSpecific: string; }
interface ModelC { id: string; }
```

with these two `Observable`s of them:

```js
const a$: Observable<ModelA[]> = of([{ aSpecific: "a-1" }, { aSpecific: "a-2" }]);
const b$: Observable<ModelB[]> = of([{ bSpecific: "b-1" }, { bSpecific: "b-2" }]);
```

Now, create 2 `Observables` that maps to `ModelC`:

```js
const mappedA$: Observable<ModelC[]> = a$.pipe(map(a => a.map(({ aSpecific: id }) => ({ id }))));

const mappedB$: Observable<ModelC[]> = b$.pipe(map(b => b.map(({ bSpecific: id }) => ({ id }))));
```

Lastly, merge them with `combineLAtest` and `mergeAll` to unfold the first "array of arrays"

```js
const c$: Observable<ModelC[]> = combineLatest(mappedA$, mappedB$).pipe(
  mergeAll()
);
```

You can find the full source code in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-hfkuye?devtoolsheight=60)